# How to convert a double from power of 10 notation to decimal?

Tags: c#, double, decimal

The method I'm using returns a double number. The number can have a total maximum of up to 8 decimal signs after 0. When the decimals are close to 1 it would return something like 0.045. But when the numbers get really small it starts converting it to scientific notation and I would get something like: 4.99E-06. 
How do I take this variable and convert it to a decimal so it would appear as 0.00000470?

Comment: Where are you using this variable that it is converting to scientific notation? Just in the debugger?

Comment: I think sharing some code would be helpful.

Comment: The value in question is being return from an API call

Comment: Did you do any research on this question whatsoever?  Starting with, perhaps, reading the documentation for `double.ToString` ?

Comment: And I am confused as to why you would expect `4.99e-6` to be displayed as `0.00000470`, and not `0.00000499`.  Where did the extra `0.00000029` go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do something like this:

```
double myValue = 0.000007812345d;
string myValueAsString = myValue.ToString("F20");
Console.Out.WriteLine(myValueAsString);
```

Where F20 specifies that you want a fixed point output with 20 decimal digits after the decimal place. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Later if you need to convert the string value back to a double, you could do something like this:

```
double myConvertedValue = Double.Parse(myValueAsString);
Console.Out.WriteLine(myConvertedValue); // note that this string is treated with scientific notation
```

You would only have to do this if the original double variable was out of scope. Otherwise, just use the original double for your calculations, etc.

Comment: so it will be turned into a string, and if later on I want to use it as a number again, then I can convert it back to double?

Comment: Yes you would just use Double.Parse

Comment: @SSJ5Broli: No, *a new string is produced*. When you say "what's the text of 123?" the number 123 does not stop being a number. It's still a number. Your double is unchanged by asking the question "how do you render as a string?"

Comment: Thinking like with a web application, I figured the OP would use the value and need to convert it back later. @Eric Lippert is right that you could continue to use the original double if that variable is still in scope.

Comment: ok thanks it looks like the number still works irregardless wether it's being displayed as a E or a decimal